# How to prepend/(insert a string) in a file at arbitrary line numbers to multiple files in a directory?

Tags: linux, unix, shell

Appending can be done using tee command.

```
cat file | tee -a >> *
```

Is there a way to do a prepend/insertion?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using sed might help

example:

```
sed -i.bak '3 r tmp1.txt' settings.xml
```

will add the contents of tmp1.txt after line 3 in settings.xml (and create a backup file with the .bak extension)

Comment: To add a string of txt to the file: `sed -i.bak "3 a foo $USER bar" settings.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Just a brief example: say, comment out specific/particular/arbitrary C lines:

```
$ echo -e "1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n" | sed "3s,^,/* ,;5s,$, */,"
1
2
/* 3
4
5 */
6
```

Note:

- single `sed` command follows a format `"${linenum}s/${search}/${replace}/"`
- then two commands can be delimited by a semicolon '`;`'
- using a comma '`,`' as delimiter, for easier reading of `s///`
- Caret '`^`' matches start of line; dollar '`$`' matches end of line; the `s///` will replace *only* those (meta?)"characters"

Of course, then this should be modified with the `-i` switch to `sed`, to eventually replace file contents..

Cheers!

EDIT: Refs:

- [Can we give multiple patterns to a sed command??? - The UNIX and Linux Forums](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/36463-can-we-give-multiple-patterns-sed-command.html)
- [Cute ‘sed’ Tricks to Modify Specific Lines Within File | The Linux Daily](http://www.thelinuxdaily.com/2011/02/cute-sed-tricks-to-modify-specific-lines-within-file/)